# Output of the login and registration form in the site header (OpenCart 2.1)

Tags: php, opencart

Good day!
There was a following problem. By design, the login and registration forms must be in the site header.
I tried to do the following:

In home.php

$ Data ['login'] = $ this-> load-> controller ('account / login');

In home.tpl

echo $ login;

In login.tpl is the form itself.
There is no result. Tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? echo the login in the header?